# jQuery updates DOM, browser does not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a project where for example field number 3 on the webpage should be updated with values from a database when a user enters data into field number 1. This already works fine without any problems.

But if the user modifies field number 3 first and field number 1 at a later time, just the DOM gets updated (as I can tell from Firebug) but there isn't any visible change on field number 3 to the user.

I created a very basic version of this problem and still I am not able to tell what's wrong here.

HTML

```
<div id="container1">
  <textarea id="container1.1">Entry 1.1</textarea>
  <textarea id="container1.2">Entry 1.2</textarea>
  <textarea id="container1.3">Entry 1.3</textarea>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').change(function() {
    var clickedObject = $(this);
    var id            = $(this).attr('id').substr(9);
    var value         = $(this).val();
    var dataString    = "id=" + id + "&value=" + value;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(Result)
      {
        if(Result == '-')
        {
          console.log('Nothing to do');
        } else {
          clickedObject.next().next().html(Result);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
  if ($_POST['id'] == '1.1') {
    echo 'Modified string';
  } else {
    echo '-';
  }
?>
```

Comment: why would you have 2 text area with the same id?

Comment: Thanks. Just a typo, doesn't affect the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set values of textarea by .val() method, instead of html().

And maybe it will be more descriptive if you will use only one id of textarea that should call request on changes.

Comment: This is the solution, although some more explanation as to the difference between the value and html of a textarea would be nice.

Comment: .html() method is used for tags like <div>,<span>,<p>,<h1>  

.val() method is used for input tags like <input>, <textarea>

Comment: It works on textareas too, it's just that the HTML content of the element is the default value, not the current value.

Comment: that's why html() is actually useless for inputs

Comment: Inputs are different, they are empty elements and have no child nodes at all.

Comment: I mean inputs like a mutable elements on the page, that can be changed

Comment: There are times when it is useful to set or read the default value of a textarea.